# Compiling Java on Tomcat/JSP Hosting

Tags: java, php

I'm thinking of purchesing hosting from a company that has Tomcat/JSP install on their servers (arvixe.com/linux_web_hosting). I wish to know if I need tomcat/jsp in order to compile a .java file on the webserver. What I would like to do is for a visitor to upload a .java file and for the server to compile it into a java webapplet. For example:

1. Visitor uploads their .java file.
2. Server compiles the .java into a .class.
3. Server signs the .class and makes a .jar.
4. Once done the visitor can download the .jar and use it for personal use.

What would I need in order to do this? I already know how to do it on the computer with Java installed, but I would like to do it on the webhost as well. If I can do this I would like to do it with PHP if possible.

Comment: Well, step 1 is easy to do in PHP; now, if you can run an external process, just find out where Java is installed and run steps 2 and 3 as you would do on your computer. Hosting is no different.

Comment: @alf How would I be able to do this though? Anyone make a tutorial or anything like that?

Comment: If you can get hold of ssh console of your hosting, start with `which javac`—this will give you a hint on where your Java runtime is and whether it's in fact available. After that, just do steps 2 and 3 exactly as you would do those locally from a command line. As of tutorials, check out http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: @alf Okay, so with a hosting company that has Tomcat/JSP I can compile .java files on the hosting companies servers without any problems? How would I get a hole of the ssh console? Where is that located?

Comment: It may or may not be possible; I'm afraid it will be much faster to ask hosting company's support directly.

Comment: @alf I am, but they don't know eather. I've been on chat with them for 1 hour.

Comment: I guess it's a good time to change hosting :) If support cannot direst you to `ssh`, it's not the best testimonial for the support.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile java directly inside of Java, if you are on 1.6 or higher... here's an article about it:
http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-1.html

Comment: I'm trying to compile it through my hosting.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, if the version of Java used by the Tomcat setup is Java 1.6 or later, then you can use the Compiler API to compile Java programmatically. If the server is running Tomcat, then I would really just do it in a Servlet -- I can't quite see the rationale for wanting to shoehorn PHP into the equation if you have a working Tomcat server and you want to compile Java...

However, it sounds like your application is "server functionality heavy" enough that you might want to think about choosing a hosting plan that isn't too restrictive: ideally I'd go for a virtual server with full shell access and allowing you to install whatever you need. If the company is telling you that you can only use a particular version of Tomcat/Java, then that would ring alarm bells for me. (Of course, if they're just saying "install what you like, but if you use this particular version, we will give you additional assistance", then that's another story.)